# How to debug a variable in a controller class (var_dump)

Tags: nodes, debugging, page-controller

I am trying to do a var dump from a Drupal 8 Controller class. This is not working because controllers need to send a response. I just need to see the contents of a variable and I have not idea how to do this since I've tried all response combinations and can't seem to get it working.

This is my variable.

```
$storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node');
$node = $storage->load($rep_id);
```

I am trying to `var_dump($node)` to see what's in it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

return new Response('<pre>' . var_export($node, TRUE) . '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 3):

OK, I'm going to be *that guy.* Do yourself a favour and set up Xdebug, hacks like var_dump() or var_export() are very bad practice and sooner or later you will forget to remove some of those statements and it will end up in production. Also it takes one single click to set up a breakpoint, as opposed to writing a var_dump()  or var_export() statement. Not to mention that the amount of information you can get by using a debugger is vastly more comprehensive.

Comment: By _that guy_ I assume you mean _that sensible, less-stressed guy_ :)

Comment: Good advice. Admittedly, I'm still not great at debugging, but I'm definitely open to better methods.

Answer (score 2):

While there's a few options, you could try:

```
drupal_set_message('<pre>' . var_export($node, 1) . '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

These are some other techniques:

**1] Debug**

- Drupal core comes with its own function [debug()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21common.inc/function/debug/8.2.x)

**2] Devel**

- intstall `composer require symfony/var-dumper`
- clear cache with UI or `drush cr`
- at devel settings page set var-dumper as a default option
- use devel functions `dpm()` `kpr()` for inspecting variables in your code
- `{{ devel_dump() }}`, `{{ kpr() }}` or `{{ dpm() }}` in twig templates

**3] Other contributed modules**

- Try [VarDumper](https://www.drupal.org/project/vardumper) or [Ladybug](https://www.drupal.org/project/ld)

**Note:** (Read Jaypan's answer) You can also use PHP's native functions like `var_dump` or `print_r`